# How to lock an android device with a given PIN or Password?

Tags: android

I want to lock the android device using a given PIN or Password. How can I do that? I have searched many pages. But they are not helpful. I heard about something called `DevicePolicyManager` class. Can anybody explain how to lock our device with a given PIN or Password? Thank you...

Comment: Indication : lockNow.

Comment: @SoothSayer What are the permissions needed for using this function...?

Comment: There is not permissions, you have to create a /res/xml/admin.xml file and define the uses-policies, and a Receiver. Go here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html

Comment: @SoothSayer Thanks friend. I have solved my question using this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745890/how-do-i-lock-phone-programmatically-android
And thanks for your support.